# How to fix the ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser'?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, importerror

I'm doing a project using python 3.7 and beautifulsoup4-4.8.0. I found a might-not-be-correct solution to fix the ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser'. If you could help me verify it, it would be greatly appreciated!

******************* Issue ********************

I'm outputting the original error I got here to help illustrate what I did and why I did this.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Youtube.py", line 1, in 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 29, in 
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/**init**.py", line 294, in 
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 7, in 
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/html/parser.py)

*************** My solution *****************

In the error output, it shows that we cannot import 'HTMLParseError' from the file 'html.parser', where it was supposed to be implemented. so I did my research(https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.parser.html) and found out that HTMLParseError was deprecated since version 3.3, and was removed in version 3.5: It turned out that this exception was never raised by the parser using default non-strict mode (which I believe is what I'm using).

SOOOOO basically what I did was just to remove that line of code that imports the 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser', located in the file (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py)

and voilà! It erased the error. I don't know if it is technically correct. If someone can help me verify this solution, it would be really really appreciated!

Comment: That ImportError never should have reached you in the first place - BeautifulSoup includes code that's supposed to handle it automatically. It's possible that edits you performed broke BeautifulSoup's handling. Try uninstalling and reinstalling bs4.

Comment: Ok yeah. I was not using the correct version. I had to run pip3 install —ignore-installed beautifulsoup4 to install the py3 comparable version, since bs4 is distutils Installed (my real issue here lol).  And they did handle this error in the py3 version by adding a try except block and my error was resolved. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4 --force-reinstall
$ python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4 --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve my problem by running the following command.

```
pip3 install —ignore-installed beautifulsoup4
```

My issue was that I was not using the py3 compatible version of bs4. because bs4 is distutils Installed, I had to use the —ignore-installed flag to resolve my ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'beautifulsoup4'. It is a distutils installed project...

Thanks to user2357112's comment!

Comment: This did not work to fix a mixed-up install of bs4 for Python2 and Python3 on Fedora 35, but the above answer by most wanted, with the additional 'python3 -m pip install...' line fixed things.