# How do you run BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I do a course on coursera, Python for everybody. I am stuck on the 3rd course, week 4.

My problem is that when I try to run Beautifulsoup, it has a traceback. I am uploading 2 pics, one my code and one my traceback. I tried downloading it from the web, the tried from the course folder, and then tried it from the command prompt, using python -m pip install beautifulsoup. None of there are working. I really need to know how to run BeautifulSoup because i have to submit my code soon. So if you can explain how to run BeautifulSoup I would appreciate it. (Also would appreciate if you explained the traceback!)

Thanks!

[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RmsH.png)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4yZR.png)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.find_all("span"))


    #tags = soup('a')
    #for tag in tags:
    #print('TAG:', tag)
    #print('URL:', tag.get('href', None))
    #print('Contents:', tag.contents[0])
    #print('Attrs:', tag.attrs)
```

[image: my trace after I installed the other version of beautifulsoup]

Comment: Please paste the actual text of your error and your code instead of just screenshots.

Comment: sure. Can you not see it?

Comment: I can; however, I can't copy/paste it to reproduce & investigate, and it's also not good for screen readers and other accessibility tools.

Comment: The code snippet is working here with Python3 and beautiful soup 4, can you verify your environment?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "enviroment" ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're having a circular imports issue.  I think it's because you're importing `bs4` but you also have a folder `bs4` next to your Python file.  Try removing/renaming that folder.

Comment: so do i rename the file named bs4 in my ef file?

Comment: Yes.  It's a folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code snippet but your installation of Beautiful soup. Try reinstalling beautiful soup with

```
pip3 install —ignore-installed beautifulsoup4
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650354/13522090)

Comment: from the other replies i got, I tried renaming another file bs5, because it was bs4, which still didnt work. I installed what you said and for some reason it still doesnt work. I will edit to show another screenshot

Comment: before, bs4 was installed but wasn't working (the traceback) and I answered the reason why I think it doesn't work. **But now bs4 isn't installed at all. It's isn't in the interpreter's path**

Comment: If you installed with pip as I suggested in my answer it will automatically be in **sys.path** and will be picked up by the interpreter